# Basic math and how to display answer

Tags: nsstring, ibaction

Could one of you Gurus take a look at this string and give me a hand.. I would like 
        label1.text = display answer to g
        label2.text = display answer to h
        label3.text = display answer to i

all the numbers input and out put will be 4 places after the decimal ... i.e. , 1.2345

```
    (IBAction)calculate1 {
        float a = ([textField1.text doubleValue]);
        float b = ([textField2.text doubleValue]);
        float c = ([textField3.text doubleValue]);
        float d = ([textField4.text doubleValue]);
        float e = ([textField5.text doubleValue]);
        float f = ([textField6.text doubleValue]);
        float g = ([textField1.text doubleValue]+[textField2.text doubleValue]+[textField3.text doubleValue]);
        float h = ([textField4.text doubleValue]+[textField5.text doubleValue]+[textField6.text doubleValue]);
        float i = ((309.5)/([textField7.text doubleValue]+234.5));

        label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", g];
        label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", h];
        label3.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", i];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use format specifier like **@"%.4f"** in initWithFormat method. Also, i guess that your a, b, c, d, (...) variables must be **double**.